# Get array data in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to extract the data in an array, however, it seems I am not doing it right, but when i console log it, I can see all the data. I want to be able to extract only all the titles in the array. Kindly show me where I am getting it wrong.

```
      const movies = [
       {
         title: 'Show stopper',
         rate: 5,
         runtime: 120,
         information: 'Show stopper is available',
       },
       {
         title: 'Drive through',
         rate: 233,
         runtime: 65,
         information: 'Drive through is not available',
       },
      ];

        componentDidMount() {
          this.getItemValues();
        }

        getItemValues = () => {
          const { title, rate } = movies;

          console.log(title, rate);
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the context of this code? Is it inside of a class/component?

Comment: Your `movies` variable is an array with objects in it. Your destructuring declaration indicates that you want to get the values of the properties "title" and "rate", but the **array** has no such properties. The objects in the array do, but you'd have to iterate through the array and do something with each object individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Movies is an array not, just one object with the keys title and rate. You could iterate through the elements of the array using a for loop or a forEach. For example:

```
getItemValues = () => {
  movies.forEach((element) => console.log(element.title, element.rate));
}
```

That would print out all your titles and rates. You are close to doing what you want, just keep in mind the type of what you are sending into variables and functions.

To answer your question: you could

```
let titles = [];
getItemTitles = () {
   movies.forEach((movie) => titles.push(movie.title);)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963920/get-array-data-in-a-function#comment104182957_58963920) is right.

You can't destructure an array like that.

You'd need to iterate over your array and store the values.

```
movies.map(e => {   
    return {
    title: e.title, 
    rate: e.rate 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - this without a doubt the easiest way to achieve your objective:

```js
const movies = [{
  title: 'Show stopper',
  rate: 5,
  runtime: 120,
  information: 'Show stopper is available',
}, {
  title: 'Drive through',
  rate: 233,
  runtime: 65,
  information: 'Drive through is not available',
}];

const titles = movies.map(movie => movie.title);

console.log(titles)
```

Therefore, using this approach, your React code would look something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getItemValues();
}

getItemValues = () => {
    const titles = movies.map(movie => movie.title);
    console.log(titles);
}
```

**FYI**: [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring), while similar, use different syntaxes and should be used properly. In your code, *you are attempting to destructure an array using object destructuring* syntax which will not work as you expect).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const titles = this.getItemValues();
    console.log(titles);
}

getItemValues = () => movies.map(movie => movie.title);
```